# ASP.net The resource cannot be found . Redirects to a page that its not supposed to redirect to

Tags: asp.net

I'm running a personal project Im doing on Local on my computer.
My entire project is running perfectly however when I get to the page called inbox it loads for the first time but after I press on anything on that page such as compose or "Read" a message I get the error.

> Server Error in '/FinalProject' Application.
>   The resource cannot be found.
>   Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly. 
>    Requested URL: /FinalProject/Default.apsx
>    Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET 
>    Version:4.7.3056.0

Now the page has no redirect whatsoever to the default page that its redirecting to (theres no response.redirect to it anywhere on the page that the error is happening on). its not mentioned even once. not to mention the page the error is giving for is spelt wrong(.apsx instead of .aspx) however I can't seem to be able to find it in the page if the the error code does exist. 
The only possible pages I could thing this might happen on is the page i get the error on or the masterpage but non of them has a false response redirect. 
I'm working on Visual web developer express 2010.

Any suggestions ways to fix this? Would just like to mention that until a few days ago this worked perfectly. No changes were made in the coding therefore I don't know whats causing the issue.

Comment: what does the codefile property set as in the first tag.

Answer (score 0):

When you press on any button that might cause a PostBack. Check 'onClick()' references in your button controls.